# Having problems creating Jar file on IntelliJ using JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

Lately I have been working on a personal project of mine and I decided to use JavaFX . The IDE I'm using is IntelliJ IDEA and I am having headaches to actually make a Jar out of this . I have tried lots of tutorials and nothing seems to work . I would be very grateful if anyone could give me some hints on what's wrong .

Firstly I tried to include all the dependencies on the Project Structure tab and built the artifacts
needed .

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk2js.png
```

The resulting Jar file does not work, when I try to run it I get the following error :

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Even though the Jar was pretty useless I found a way to make it "work" , I ran the following command on cmd

```
java --module-path "%Path to JavaFX SDK%" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar %Path to Jar%
```

So I decided to search what could be missing and tried several solutions but non work , one of them was trying to create a dummy class that did not extend Application as a main class , but this lead to disaster since I got this result :

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no 
suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I even tried to do this all by hand since I was suspicious IntelliJ was omitting steps , needless to say it also didn't end well . I will also leave some prints with the project structure in the hope of helping to understand what's wrong.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk2js.png 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCoWl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUqHd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWv1f.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXtc6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQjMO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQeuu.png
```

Comment: What JDK do you use? Does it have JavaFX included? Please follow for the solution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200721#focus=Comments-27-4648706.0-0